# The image is not being visible at the image view

Tags: java, android

My xml file is as shown below, when i select image the cursor select the image 
 but the image is not appearing in my image view.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context="com.appsound.instagram.memeappgenerator.MainActivity">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:hint="@string/entertopmemetext" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:hint="@string/enterbottommemetext"
        android:id="@+id/editBottom"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/add_image"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="#F44336"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:onClick="addImage"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="TRY"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="#E1F5"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:onClick="trymeme" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/memeImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/meme_top_text"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/memeTopText"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/memeBottomText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/meme_bottom_text"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="#F44336"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:onClick="saveImage"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

my java code is as shown below.

```
package com.appsound.instagram.memeappgenerator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView topText;
    TextView bottomText;
    EditText editTop;
    EditText editBottom;
    ImageView imageView;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        topText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.memeTopText);
        bottomText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.memeBottomText);
        editTop=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTop);
        editBottom=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editBottom);
        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.memeImage);
    }
    public void addImage(View view){
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent,RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && requestCode==RESULT_OK && null!=data){
            Uri selectedImage= data.getData();
            String[] filepathcolumn={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filepathcolumn,null,null,null);
            assert cursor != null;
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex=cursor.getColumnIndex(filepathcolumn[0]);
            String picturePath= cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.memeImage);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }

    }
    public void trymeme(View view){
        topText.setText(editTop.getText().toString());
        bottomText.setText(editBottom.getText().toString());
        hideKeyboard(view);
    }
    public void hideKeyboard(View view){
        InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),0);
    }
}
```

have a great problem on the image upload on the Image view, the image upload button is working properly and fetches the image but the image is not able to be shown on the image view am stack. please help me i shall be very glad.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**Try this fro OnActivityResult**

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }


    }
```

Comment: the code worked like miracle thankyou my boss thankyou thankyou